# How to pass a value to an arrary to be include in Affiliate Tracking URL?

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, url, affiliate

I am trying to pass an additional value to a string for an affiliate tracking module URL.

The value is a channel ID which should appear after the currency code like as follows:

cr=GBP&ch=aw

The problem is I can't get it to pass, I can see the **ch** parameter in the url but not the **aw**

```
http://www.awin1.com/sread.js?a=5914&b=399.99&cr=USD&c=100000008&d=default:399.99&vc=&t=1&**ch**=&cks=&l=http
```

Here's my code from system.xml

```
                <channel>
                    <label>Channel</label>
                    <frontent_type>text</frontent_type>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </channel>
```

First array:

```
$data = array('tt'      => 'ns',
    'tv'        => '2',
    'merchant'=> $_pr_settings['program_id'],
    'amount'    => $_orderdata['item_total_sale_count'],
    'ref'       => $_orderdata['increment_id'],
    'parts' => implode('|',$parts),
    'vc'        => $_orderdata['coupon_code'],
    'testmode'=> $_settings['test'],
    'cr'        => $_orderdata['global_currency_code'],
    'ch'      => $_setting['channel']);
```

Image pixel

```
$html .= '<img src="https://www.awin1.com/sread.img?'.implode('&amp;', $noscript_string,'&amp;', 'ch=aw').'" />
```

The sale channel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var AWIN = {};
AWIN.Tracking = {};
AWIN.Tracking.Sale = {};
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = \''.$_orderdata['item_total_sale_count'].'\';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = \''.$_orderdata['global_currency_code'].'\';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = \''.$_orderdata['increment_id'].'\';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = \''.implode('|',$parts).'\';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = \''.$_orderdata['coupon_code'].'\';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = \''.$_settings['test'].'\';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.channel = \''.$_settings['aw'].'\';
//]]>
</script>';
```

I've been here allday trying to figure out what I've done wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is really a Magento question, but the two times you use the array you use a different element in the array:

```
'ch'      => $_setting['channel']);
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.channel = \''.$_settings['aw'].'\';
```

Without know more about the system etc I would suggest that these two should be the same element.